# Appending lists of strings (nested lists) to existing list in a loop

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I need to: go over a list of text files, get file names without the path or extension, split the names into lists and create a list of those lists. The file names are in the format A1_name_id_year.txt.

The list of lists will be used to export to a .csv file.

This is the code I got so far, works fine for stripping file names.

```
file_list = []
for file_name in glob.glob("C:/path/*.txt"):
    file_list.append(file_name)
file_name_nopath = os.path.basename(file_name)
file_name_noext = [os.path.splitext(file_name_nopath)[0]]
```

This is the part that I need to change:

```
big_list = []
while len(big_list)<len(file_list):
    for n in file_name_noext:
        file_name_elements = n.split("_")
    big_list.append(file_name_elements)

print(big_list)
```

The result is as follows:

```
[['A1', 'name1', 'id1', 'year1']]
[['A2', 'name2', 'id2', 'year2'], ['A2', 'name2', 'id2', 'year2']]
[['A3', 'name3', 'id3', 'year3'], ['A3', 'name3', 'id3', 'year3'], ['A3', 'name3', 'id3', 'year3']]
...
```

However, I am trying to get a list of lists looking like this:

```
[['A1', 'name1', 'id1', 'year1'], ['A2', 'name2', 'id2', 'year2'], ['A3', 'name3', 'id3', 'year3'], ...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use `while len(big_list)<len(file_list)`. Using a [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), the following should work for you:

```
big_list = [n.split("_") for n in file_name_noext]
```

The above line of code is equivalent to:

```
big_list = []

for n in file_name_noext:
    big_list.append(n.split("_"))
```

If I understand well what you want to do, the following would be the whole code that you need:

```
file_list = []
big_list = []

for file_name in glob.glob("C:/path/*.txt"):
    name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_name))[0]
    file_list.append(name)

for n in file_list:
    big_list.append(n.split("_"))
```

It can also be written in one `for` loop like below:

```
big_list = []

for file_name in glob.glob("C:/path/*.txt"):
    name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_name))[0]
    big_list.append(name.split("_"))
```